# linking map address using linkify in android

Tags: android, linkify

The following code don't work-

```
   TextView myLocation = new TextView(this);
   myLocation.setText("Sodala, Jaipur, Rajasthan, IN");
   Linkify.addLinks(myLocation , Linkify.MAP_ADDRESSES);
   mainLayout.addView(myLocation);
```

Comment: Not every address will be recognized by `Linkify`, as there are too many possible address patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your address is too vague for Linkify. I am unaware of what addresses look like in India (if they are different at all), so consider New York in the US:

```
myLocation.setText("New York, NY   34 Maint St New York, NY");
```

"New York, NY" alone is not a valid map address for Linkify.

You can try to set your own pattern, by following [an example here](http://www.aviyehuda.com/2011/01/android-creating-links-using-linkfy/) to match anything with ", IN".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version of *addLinks* with a custom pattern.:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*", Pattern.DOTALL);
addressTextView.setText(address);
Linkify.addLinks(addressTextView, pattern, "geo:0,0?q=");
```

I use this for german and US addresses, since google-maps is pretty smart when searching an address other localities should work find too.

This highlight's all the content's of the *TextView* which fits my use-case. If the address is somewhere inside of the string a smarter pattern needs to be applied here.

Answer (score 0):

you try

http://www.aviyehuda.com/2011/01/android-creating-links-using-linkfy/

```
// Recognize all of the default link text patterns 
    Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.ALL);
```

or
http://www.aviyehuda.com/2011/01/android-creating-links-using-linkfy/

```
TextView myCustomLink2 = new TextView(this);
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+");
myCustomLink2.setText("press one of these words to search it on google: Android Linkify dzone");
Linkify.addLinks(myCustomLink2,pattern2, "http://www.google.ie/search?q=", myMatchFilter, null);
```